# Подскажите как реализовать функцию для рандомных элементов?

Tags: javascript

Ребята строго не судите мой код я только учусь! Но конструктивной критике буду рад!

проблема следующая решил для практики создать что то на подобие страницы с вкладками на которых игры простые! вот на втором этапе завис и не могу решить проблема в том что мне нужно что бы объекты #rock+i которые я создаю в js появлялись с разной периодичностью и двигались в низ с разной скоростью пробовал многое получалось сделать только так что бы одновременно и с одной и той же скоростью они двигались. Крч получается все кроме задуманного. Пробовал и через массив и через цикл. как можно реализовать такое? подскажите плз! Да и в принципе если есть возможность было бы не плохо получить мнение профессионалов по моему коду, понятно что он кривой но хотелось бы узнать на чем нужно поработать мне!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var $btn = document.querySelector('#start');
var $game = document.querySelector('#game');
var $time =document.querySelector('#time') ;
var $app = document.querySelector('.wrapper-marks-js');
var $isGame = false;
var $timeHeader = document.querySelector('#time-header');
var $result = document.querySelector('#result-header');
var $resultText = 0;
var $appContent = document.querySelector('#app');
var $appContentId = document.querySelectorAll('.app');


$btn.addEventListener('click',startGame);

function startGame (){
    $timeHeader.classList.remove('hide');
    $result.classList.add('hide');
    $resultText=0;
    document.querySelector('#result').textContent = $resultText;
    $isGame = true;
    if ($isGame && document.querySelector('#game-time').value>0 ){
        var $valueTime = document.querySelector('#game-time').value;
        $time.textContent = $valueTime;
        var interval = setInterval(function (){
            var time = parseFloat($time.textContent);
            if (time<=0){
                clearInterval(interval);
               endGame();
            }else{
                $time.textContent = (time-0.1).toFixed(1); 
            }
        },100);
    
        $btn.classList.add('hide');
        $game.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
        renderBox();
    }else{
        
    }
}


function renderBox(){
var box = document.createElement('div');
var size = Math.round(Math.random()*(100-20)+20);
var left = Math.round(Math.random()*(207-5)+5);
var top = Math.round(Math.random()*(207-5)+5);

///случайная генерация цвета
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
  }

box.style.height = box.style.width = size+'px';
box.style.position = 'absolute';
box.style.backgroundColor =  getRandomColor();
box.style.top = top+'px';
box.style.left = left+'px';
box.style.cursor = 'pointer';
box.classList.add('box-last');

$game.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin",box);

if ($isGame){
    box.addEventListener('click',function(){
        box.remove();
        renderBox();
        $resultText+=1;
        document.querySelector('#result').textContent = $resultText;
        });
}else{
    box.remove();
}
}

function endGame(){
    $isGame = false;
    $btn.classList.remove('hide');
    $game.style.backgroundColor = '#ccc';
    $timeHeader.classList.add('hide');
    $result.classList.remove('hide');
    var $hideBox = document.querySelector('.box-last');
    $hideBox.classList.add('hide');
}
 colors=['red','green','blue'];
 colors[0] = '#ff9393' ;
 colors[30] = 'green' ;
 colors[60] = 'blue' ;
 colors[90] = 'red' ;


// вкладки игровые
for (i=0; i<30*4; i+=30){
    var radio = document.createElement('input');
    radio.setAttribute('id','tab-btn-'+i);
    radio.setAttribute('name','tab-btn-radio');
    radio.setAttribute('type','radio');
    radio.classList.add('radio-tbs');
    var mark = document.createElement('label');
    mark.setAttribute('for','tab-btn-'+i);
    mark.classList.add('mark_game');
    mark.style.left = 40+i+'px';
    $app.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin",mark);
    $app.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin",radio);
    mark.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];


    radio.addEventListener('change',function(){
        for (i=0; i<4; i++){
            $appContentId[i].classList.remove('show');
        }
       idNumber= this.getAttribute('id');
       var isNumber;
       var Show;
       if (idNumber.length === 9){
        isNumber= idNumber.slice(-2);
        Show= 'app'+isNumber;
       }else if(idNumber.length === 10){
        isNumber= idNumber.slice(-3);
        Show= 'app'+isNumber;
       }
       Show= 'app'+isNumber;
       idContent = document.querySelector('#'+Show);
       idContent.classList.add('show');
       idContent.style.backgroundColor=colors[isNumber.substr(1)];
    });
}


// ---------Game-Two-----------



var $btnTwo = document.querySelector('#start-two');
var $gameTwo = document.querySelector('#game-two');
var $plane = document.querySelector('.plane');

$btnTwo.addEventListener('click',startGameTwo);

function  startGameTwo (){
    $gameTwo.style.backgroundImage = "url('img/space.jpg')";
    $btnTwo.classList.add('hide');
    $rock= document.querySelector('#rock');
    var go = true;
        document.addEventListener('keydown', function manual(event){
            // console.log('Key: ', event.key);
            // console.log('keyCode: ', event.keyCode);
            // console.log( $plane.style.left);
            if(event.keyCode === 65){
                string=$plane.style.left.substring(0, $plane.style.left.length - 1);
                $plane.style.left = Number(string)-2+'%'; 
                if(Number(string)<=4){
                    $plane.style.left = 4+'%';
                }
               console.log(string);
               console.log(go);
            }else if(event.keyCode === 68){
                string=$plane.style.left.substring(0, $plane.style.left.length - 1);
                $plane.style.left = Number(string)+2+'%'; 
                if(Number(string)>=96){
                    $plane.style.left = 96+'%';
                }
            }else if(event.keyCode === 87){
                string=$plane.style.bottom.substring(0, $plane.style.bottom.length - 1);
                $plane.style.bottom = Number(string)+2+'%'; 
                if(Number(string)>=20){
                    $plane.style.bottom = 20+'%';
                }
            }else if(event.keyCode === 83){
                string=$plane.style.bottom.substring(0, $plane.style.bottom.length - 1);
                $plane.style.bottom = Number(string)-2+'%'; 
                if(Number(string)<=0){
                    $plane.style.bottom = 0+'%';
                }
            }
        });
        
        

        

        function rockdrop(){
            time = Math.round(Math.random()*(50-10)+10);

            for (i=0; i<=5; i++){
                var rockSide = Math.round(Math.random()*(94-6)+6);
                $rockItem = document.createElement('img');
                $gameTwo.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin",$rockItem);
                $rockItem.setAttribute('id',"rock"+i);
                rockId= document.querySelector('#rock'+i);
                rockId.style.bottom = 575+'px';
                rockId.style.left = rockSide+'%';
                $rockItem.setAttribute('src',"./img/rock (1).svg");
                $rockItem.classList.add('rock');
                
            }
            $rockArray=Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.rock'));

            function dropDown (Item){
                Item.style.bottom = parseInt(Item.style.bottom)-1+'px';
            }
            
            console.log($rockArray);
            function drop (){
                for (var key in $rockArray){
                    
                    setTimeout(setInterval(dropDown($rockArray[key]),time),time);
                        if ( parseInt($rockArray[key].style.bottom) <= -53){
                                                       
                            $rockArray[key].remove();
                                
                        }
                }
            }
        drop();
        }
        rockdrop();
    }
    
    
    // это мои попытки реализовать функцию.
    
    
//                 if(document.getElementsByClassName('rock').length > 0){
//                     $rockArray=Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.rock'));
                    
//                         for (var key in $rockArray){
//                             function drop (){
                    
//                                 $rockArray[key].style.bottom = parseInt($rockArray[key].style.bottom)-1+'px';
//                                 if ( parseInt($rockArray[key].style.bottom) <= -53){
                                   
//                                     $rockArray[key].remove();
            
//                                 }else{
//                                     // rockdrop(); 
//                                 }
//                             }
//                             setInterval(drop,time);
                        
//                     }
//                         }
    
    
//                 setTimeout(setInterval(drop(),100),500);
                
//                 if (document.getElementsByClassName('rock').length >= 5){
//                     break;
//                 }else if(document.getElementsByClassName('rock').length < 5){  
//                     // for(s=0; s<=5; s++){
//                     //     time = Math.round(Math.random()*(600-500)+500);
//                     //     setInterval(rockdrop(s),time);
//                     //     setTimeout(setInterval(drop,100),time);
//                     // }
//                 }
               
//               iterator+=1;
    

//             }
            
             
                
        
            

   
// }
// var $rockArray = document.querySelectorAll('.rock');
// rockdrop();
```

```css
 /* Animation */

 @keyframes slide {
  from {top: 0;}
  50% {top: -10;}
  to {top: -20;}
  }



  /* ---------------------------- */



* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: none;
  }
  
  body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: linear-gradient(#CB356B, #BD3F32);
  }
  
  .app {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    background: #ff9393;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 30px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0 0px 0px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12), 0 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  
  .app__header {
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .app__content {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .app__footer {
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .input {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  
  .input label {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    color: #acacac;
    font-family: GothamPro,sans-serif;
    font-size: .8rem;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.2rem;
  }
  
  .input input {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 2.8rem;
    padding: .8rem 1rem;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    line-height: 1.4;
    color: #000;
    background: #fff none;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  
  .game {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #ccc;
    min-height: 300px;
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 300px;
  }
  .game-two{
    position: relative;
    min-height: 575px;
    min-width: 575px;
    max-width: 575px;
    max-height: 575px;
    background: #ccc;
  }
  
  .hide {
    display: none!important;
  }
  
  .btn {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1rem 2.3rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: GothamPro, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.3rem;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
    background: #fad64e;
    color: #3f3f3f;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2.8rem;
    transition: transform .2s ease-in-out,box-shadow .2s ease-in-out,-webkit-transform .2s ease-in-out,-webkit-box-shadow .2s ease-in-out;
    will-change: transform;
  }
  
  .btn:disabled {
    background: #ccc!important;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #000;
    cursor: not-allowed;
  }
  
  .btn:active {
    transition: transform .1s ease-in-out,box-shadow .1s ease-in-out!important;
    transform: none!important;
    box-shadow: none!important;
  }
  
  .btn:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 6px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    transform: translateY(-1px);
  }
  .wrapper-marks{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 197px;
    height: 50px;
    background: none;
    position: relative;
    /* top: -15px;
    left: 0; */
  }
  
  .mark_game{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 28px;
    height: 50px;
    /* z-index: -1; */
    border-radius: 10px;
  
  }
  .mark_game:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    top: -20px;
    animation-duration: 0.8s;
    animation-name: slide;
  }
  .mark_game_active{
    top: -20px;
  }
  .wrapper-marks-js{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    position: absolute;
    top: 31px;
    left: -230px;

  }
  .radio-tbs{
    display: none;
  }
  
  #tab-btn-0:checked~#app-0,
  #tab-btn-30:checked~#app-30,
  #tab-btn-60:checked~#app-60,
  #tab-btn-90:checked~#app-90 {
      display: block;
    }

  input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
    top: -20px;
  }  
  .show {
 display: block;
  }
  #app-30.app {
    width: 850px

  }
  .plane {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 1%;
    /* left: 50%; */
    width: 50px;
    height: 55px;
    transform: translate(-50%);
  }
  .rock {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 55px;
    transform: translate(-50%);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>JS Game</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="wrapper-marks">
    <div class="wrapper-marks-js">
      <!-- <div class="mark_game"></div> -->
    </div>
   </div>
  <div class="app show" id="app-0">
   
    <div class="app__header">
      <h1 id="time-header">Время игры: <span id="time"></span></h1>
      <h1 id="result-header" class="hide">Ваш результат: <span id="result"></span></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="app__content">
      <button class="btn" id="start">Начать</button>

      <div class="game" id="game"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="app__footer">
      <div class="input">
        <label for="game-time">Время игры, (сек)</label>
        <input type="number" id="game-time" min="5" step="1" value="5">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="app" id="app-30">
   
    <div class="app__header">
      
    </div>
    <div class="app__content">
      <button class="btn" id="start-two">Начать</button>

      <div class="game-two" id="game-two">
        <img style="left: 50%;" class="plane" id="plane"  src="./img/plane.svg" alt="">
        <!-- <img  class="rock" id="rock"  src="./img/rock (1).svg" alt=""> -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="app__footer">
      <div class="input">
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="app" id="app-60">
   
    <div class="app__header">
      <h1 id="time-header">Вкладка 3 <span id="time"></span></h1>
      <h1 id="result-header" class="hide">Ваш результат: <span id="result"></span></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="app__content">
      <button class="btn" id="start">Начать</button>

      <div class="game" id="game"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="app__footer">
      <div class="input">
        <label for="game-time">Время игры, (сек)</label>
        <input type="number" id="game-time" min="5" step="1" value="5">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="app" id="app-90">
   
    <div class="app__header">
      <h1 id="time-header">вкладка 4 <span id="time"></span></h1>
      <h1 id="result-header" class="hide">Ваш результат: <span id="result"></span></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="app__content">
      <button class="btn" id="start">Начать</button>

      <div class="game" id="game"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="app__footer">
      <div class="input">
        <label for="game-time">Время игры, (сек)</label>
        <input type="number" id="game-time" min="5" step="1" value="5">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  

  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Что-то зеленая вкладка показывает не подгруженные маленькие изображения и они не двигаются.

Comment: ну так у меня то они есть просто я хз как тут подгружать картинку на форум что бы отображалось все как надо!! там свгшки как на картинки которые и должны двигаться! двигается там только нижняя маленькая картинка это самолет управление на WSAD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь задача появления объектов в разное время решена с помощью функции `createItemsToFall()`, которая сначала создает все временные отрезки на которых будут появляться новые объекты (исходя из `MAX_TIME` - время игры и `MAX_INTERVAL/MIN_INTERVAL` - диапазон временных интервалов появления новых объектов). Затем в цикле объявляется очередная setTimeout(), которая через текущий временной интервал добавит в `itemsToFall` новый объект.

Уже в функции `drawItems()` каждому объекту из `itemsToFall` назначаются новые координаты по Y и, если объект не достиг конца, отрисовывается. В противном случае, объект удаляется из набора (Set).

Вместо анимации на `canvas` можно так же добавлять абсолютно позиционированные html-элементы с меняющимся атрибутом `top`.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const w = canvas.width = 600;
const h = canvas.height = 180;

const MAX_SPEED = 4;
const MIN_SPEED = 1;
const MAX_SIZE = 40;
const MIN_SIZE = 15;
const MAX_TIME = 8000;
const MAX_INTERVAL = 500;
const MIN_INTERVAL = 100;

const itemsToFall = createItemsToFall();

const start = performance.now();
drawItems();

function createItem(){
    return {
        speed : ((Math.random()*(MAX_SPEED-MIN_SPEED)+MIN_SPEED)*10|0)/10,
        x : (Math.random()*(w - MAX_SIZE))|0 + MAX_SIZE/2,
        color : `rgb(${(Math.random()*255)|0},${(Math.random()*255)|0},${(Math.random()*255)|0})`,
        size : (Math.random()*(MAX_SIZE-MIN_SIZE)+MIN_SIZE)|0,
        y : 0
    }
}

function createItemsToFall(){
    const arr = [];
    const set = new Set();
    let time = 0;
    while(time < MAX_TIME){
        time += (Math.random()*(MAX_INTERVAL - MIN_INTERVAL)+MIN_INTERVAL)|0;
        arr.push(time);
    }
    arr.splice(arr.length-1, 1);
    
    arr.forEach(interval => {
        setTimeout(() => {set.add(createItem())},interval);
    })

    return set;
}

function drawItems(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
    for (let item of itemsToFall){
        item.y += item.speed;
        if(item.y-item.size/2 > h){
            itemsToFall.delete(item);
            continue;
        }
        ctx.fillStyle = item.color;
        ctx.fillRect(item.x-item.size/2,item.y-item.size/2,item.size,item.size);
    }
    let raf = requestAnimationFrame(drawItems);
    if(performance.now() > start + MAX_TIME){
        cancelAnimationFrame(raf);
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,w,h);
        ctx.font = "48px serif";
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.textBaseLine = 'middle';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
        ctx.fillText("Time is over", w/2, h/2);
    }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Слушай неплохо сейчас разберусь попробую у себя так же сделать!